# download.file with wildcard matching in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to download all the files that match a pattern from a url directory in R using download.file, but I can't get it working for even a single file.  The url is:
https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/
and the pattern match is all files like:  AIS_2019_*_18.zip

Here is what I've tried for a single file case:

```
download.file('https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_04_18.zip', 
              destfile = "AIS_2019_04_18.zip", 
              method = "wget", extra = c("-r", "-np", "-L", "--max-redirect=0"))
```

but I always get `'wget' call had nonzero exit status`

I've also tried setting method = internal and mode = w, but get ```scheme not supported in url'

Comment: Have you tried running it without `method = "wget"`? I tried it without it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to generate all the links that you can then loop through them with a `for` loop.

```r
library(glue)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

# Setup
month_dates <- glue("2019-{str_pad(1:12, width = 2, pad = '0')}-01")
days_in_months <- days_in_month(as.Date(month_dates))

# Get appropriate number of days and months combinations
months <- rep(1:12, days_in_months)
days <- unlist(mapply(function(x) str_pad(1:x, width = 2, pad = "0"),
                      days_in_months))
base_url <- "https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019"

# Put everything together
all_files <- glue("{base_url}/AIS_2019_{months}_{days}.zip")

# See results
head(all_files)
#> https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_1_01.zip
#> https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_1_02.zip
#> https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_1_03.zip
#> https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_1_04.zip
#> https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_1_05.zip
#> https://coast.noaa.gov/htdata/CMSP/AISDataHandler/2019/AIS_2019_1_06.zip

# Check number of the days in a year is correct
length(all_files)
#> [1] 365
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Once you have those created, you can do something like:

```
# Untested
for (file in all_files) {
    download.file(file, 
                  destfile = basename(file), 
                  extra = c("-r", "-np", "-L", "--max-redirect=0"))
}
```